# Android передача данных между активностями

Tags: android, activity

Нужно передать `int`'е значение или `String`'е без разницы, конвертирую. Пробовал через Intent, но для передачи нужно запускать метод `startActivity()` я так понял. Как мне передать значение без открытия активити, только передать.

Comment: Одномоментно существует только одна активити. Т.е. вы не можете из одной в другую передать, т.к. другой просто не существует в момент передачи (да, тут есть нюансы и можно накостылять реальную передачу из одной в другую, но так делать плохо и никто вам не покажет как. ибо это плохо и костыль). Используйте вариант передачи через `Intent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй сохранить данные в бд или в shared preference, а потом когда надо будет считай их во второй Activity.

Comment: Да, думал файл отдельный создать

Comment: Лучше используй встроенные средства! бд или шарид

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я знаю для этого есть Bundle
[Класс Bundle зачем он?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623829/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-bundle-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BD)

Как вариант можно передать данные из класса А в static переменную класса B. Либо использовать Singleton.